# How to run this C# code. using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

the code is as follows

```cs
static void main(string[] args)
{
   Int num = 10;
   Int num = 20;
   If (10 > 20);
   {
      return;
   }
   Console.WriteLine("10 > 20");
}
```

basically what I am trying to do is get the code to run to get the output of the program in the command window of visual studio

Comment: This code will give you output **10 > 20**, what are you really trying to do?

Comment: That is what im trying to get the output of but when I run the code I get a error. the Error is 
" A local veriable of function named 'num' is alreadyt defined in this scope"

Comment: you defined `int num` 2 times that is why this error occures

Comment: ok so I just need to put 

int num = 10,20;

Comment: @Thomas, the compiler is complaining because on the `Int num = 10;` line you declare a variable called `num` and assign the value `10` to it.  On the line beneath this line (`Int num = 20;`) you try to declare _another_ variable also called `num`, which isn't valid in C#.  If you change the first line to `Int numOne = 10;` and the second line to `Int numTwo = 20;` it should compile.

Comment: ah ok thank you I will try that thank you @simon-pearson

Comment: @simon-pearson Thank you. That worked :) I appreicate the help and explination.

Comment: You also are not using those variables. You're just comparing the constants 10 and 20. If you want to compare those variables you should do numOne > numTwo

Comment: Please let us know what are you trying to do here

Answer (score 2):

bunch of things:

1. as `int num` is defined twice

   - rename the second `int` to `num2`
2. `Int` and `If` should be `int` and `if`
3. remove the `;` after the `if(10 > 20)` line

   - also replace the `10 > 20` with `num > num2` to make the first two assignments actually useful

Answer (score 0):

you are defined variable num two times

```
static void main(string[] args)
{
Int num1 = 10;
Int num2 = 20;
If (10 > 20)
{return;}
Console.WriteLine("10 > 20");
```

Answer (score 0):

You define the variable `num` twice. Maybe you can define two variables `num1` and `num2` to store them.

```
int num1 = 10;
int num2 = 20;
```

Do you want to compare two int numbers? If so, you can refer to the following statement.

```
if(num1 > num2)
{
    //...
}
```

Besides, you want to print `"10 > 20"`, rather than `"10 < 20"`?

Comment: Thank you for this. Makes sense and it worked for me. I am grateful for the assistance.

Comment: Glad this can help you. If this answer is helpful for you, maybe you can click the `√` to mark it as the answer.